# Populate LiveCycle pdf with ColdFusion, but no fieldnames in the PDF

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, livecycle, cfpdfform

I'm trying to fill in a PDF with query data using ColdFusion. I think it does not have field names.  Is there any way I can still use `cfpdfformparam` to fill it in?

The PDF was created with LiveCycle and I cannot modify it, it comes from https://www.formulaires.modernisation.gouv.fr/gf/cerfa_10069.do

When I run this on the pdf:

```
<cfpdf action="getInfo" source="cerfa_10069.pdf" name="PDFInfo">
<cfdump var="#PDFInfo#" >

<cfpdfform source="cerfa_10069.pdf" result="resultStruct" action="read"/>
<cfdump var="#resultStruct#" >
```

it returns a struct showing

```
topmostSubform  
   struct
      Champ_de_texte1   
        array
        1   N° 10069*04
        2   [empty string]
        3   [empty string]
        4   [empty string]
```

with 24 fields unnamed but numbered.  If I could figure out the order of the fields, could I 
fill them in using just the number?  But this below does not work:

```
<cfpdfsubform name="topmostSubform"> 
    <cfpdfsubform name="Champ_de_texte1"> 

           <cfpdfformparam name="17" value="572 Evergreen Terrace"> 

    </cfpdfsubform> 
</cfpdfsubform>
```

I only need to fill in the PDF's form fields with data, not submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index` attribute of [cfpdfformparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-76ea.html):

```
<cfpdfform action="populate" source="c:/path/to/cerfa_10069-04.pdf" 
         destination="c:/path/to/updatedForm.pdf">
    <cfpdfsubform name="topmostSubform"> 
        <cfpdfformparam name="Champ_de_texte1" index="1" value="572 Evergreen Terrace" /> 
        <cfpdfformparam name="Champ_de_texte1" index="2" value="Foo" /> 
        <cfpdfformparam name="Champ_de_texte1" index="3" value="Bar" /> 
        ...
    </cfpdfsubform>
</cfpdfform>
```